# Semantic ui installation doesn't work in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, semantic-ui, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm trying to install semantic ui in my Rails 6 application but doesn't work, i'm following the guide of [this repo](https://github.com/doabit/semantic-ui-sass),(for rails 6 +) and I did some steps like this:

I added a packages with yarn:

```
yarn add jquery popper.js semantic-ui-sass
```

After this In config/webpack/environment.js I added this:

```
const webpack = require("webpack")

environment.plugins.append("Provide", new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery',
  Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
}))
```

And my last step i did this in app/javascript/packs/application.js:

```
require("semantic-ui-sass")
```

After I followed this steps that included in the guide of the repository, nothing changes at all

Answer (score 0):

In the repository link you have given this is not the last step which you have mentioned if you are using yarn to add semantic UI.
First add packages with yarn:

```
yarn add jquery popper.js @doabit/semantic-ui-sass
```

Then in config/webpack/environment.js add:

```
 

    const webpack = require('webpack')
    
    environment.plugins.append(
      'Provide',
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
      })
    )
```

Then in app/javascript/packs/application.js add:

```
import '@doabit/semantic-ui-sass'
```

Then in last step if your application is using webpacker for css files you have to import this file in your css stylesheets

```
@import '@doabit/semantic-ui-sass/src/scss/semantic-ui.scss'
```